Why is it PT symmetry not TP symmetry for Kramer Degeneracy
I understand that, under time reversal symmetry $H_k$ is transformed to $H_{-k}$, and only when we are at the points where k=-k such as in 1D the 0 and $\frac{\pi}{a}$ we would have degeneracy. And if the system also have inversion symmetry, then each k is mapped to -k, and there would be degeneracy for all the k.
So I think I have a basic understanding of why when the system has T symmetry, and P symmetry then it would have PT symmetry and the system is degenerate.
I don't quite understand in the case of maybe T, P is broken, but PT is preserved, how would that happen, can someone give me an example.

+1 but please stick to 1 question per post.

https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4051/pt-symmetry-leading-to-spin-degenerate-band-structures/4104#4104
